# How do I integrate rewrite rules to forbid requests referred from a domain with existing rewrite rules in .htaccess?

Tags: domains, htaccess

I have read about how to do this using the following:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*website\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    </IfModule>
```

However, I can't figure out how to use it in combination with what is currently there now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> block a domain

You presumably mean "block a referer".

You just need to put that bit of code *before* the existing directives. Otherwise, if you put it at the end (after the front controller) then it will never be processed.

You don't need the additional `<IfModule>` wrapper and certainly not the additional `RewriteEngine` directive (although it does no harm). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In fact, you probably don't need the `<IfModule>` wrapper at all - but if this is auto-generated by your CMS (eg. WordPress) then leave it.

But otherwise...

```
RewriteEngine On

# Block
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# Front controller
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Yes, referrer domain thank you, that works great...thanks so much!